# Android:Espresso: Check is show home button without workaround?

Tags: android, android-espresso

```
Android Studio 3.2
minSdkVersion 18
```

To check is show home button I use the next Espresso test:

```
 @Test
 fun toolbar_homeButton_isDisplayed() {
        onView(withContentDescription(R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

It's work but... it's workaround. Is it possible to write this test without workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Espresso: Can't check is NOT show home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677686/android-espresso-cant-check-is-not-show-home-button)

Comment: @AlexanderCavalheiroBecker it's not duplicate. It's another question.